# Import huge SQL file into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, bigdata, sqlcmd

I use the `sqlcmd` utility to import a 7 GB large SQL dump file into a remote SQL Server. The command I use is this:

```
sqlcmd -S IP address -U user -P password -t 0 -d database -i file.sql
```

After about 20-30 min the server regularly responds with:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Scripting error.

Any pointers or advice?

Comment: This is pushing the limits of networking technology :D I had a similar situation but i was Lucky enough to be able to do it db to db and made a pagination/retry function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `file.sql` is just a bunch of `INSERT` statements.  For a large amount of rows, I suggest using the BCP command-line utility.  This will perform orders of magnitude faster than individual `INSERT` statements.

You could also bulk insert data using the T-SQL `BULK INSERT` command.  In that case, the file path needs to be accessible by the database server (i.e. UNC path or copied to a drive on the server) and along with needed permissions.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.

Comment: You suggest that I first convert data to delimiter-separated file (e.g. CSV)?)

Comment: The default BCP character format is tab-delimited.  You can specify an different delimiter if desired.  If the source data is an export of a SQL Server table, you can create the file in native format with BCP out.  Native format is even faster.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use SSIS.  While I have a certificate as a DBA, I always try to use the right tool for the job.

Here are some reasons to use SSIS.

1 - Use can still use fast-load, bulk copy.  Make sure you set the batch size.

2 - Error handling is much better.

However, if you are using fast-load, either the batch commits or it gets tossed.

If you are using single record, you can direct each error row to a separate destination.

3 - You can perform transformations on the source data before loading it into the destination.

In short, Extract Translate Load.

4 - SSIS loves memory and buffers.  If you want to get really in depth, read some articles from Matt Mason or Brian Knight.

Last but not least, the LAN/WAN always plays a factor if the job is not running on the target server with the input file on a local disk.

If you are on the same backbone with a good pipe, things go fast.

In summary, yeah you can use BCP.  It is great for little quick jobs.  Anything complicated with robust error handling should be done with SSIS.

Good luck,